# Multiple <select> using selectize, option removal when already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectize.js

I'm new in using selectize.js, and this is the simplified version of my problem. Please see fiddle below.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KrdQ/20/)

What I want is not to select the item when it is already selected.

Ex.

- click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button and then select the full name.
- click the <kbd>Add</kbd> again.
- Full name should not be selected in the second `<select>` or should not be visible.

How will I be able to do this?

HTML

```
<button>Add</button><br/><br/>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS

```
var saveAsOptions = [
        { value: 'full-name', text: 'Full Name' },
        { value: 'first-name', text: 'First Name' },
        { value: 'last-name', text: 'Last Name' }
];

var i = 1;
var $selectSaveAs;

$('button').on('click', function(){
    
    $('#container').append(generateSaveAs(i));
    
    $selectSaveAs = $('#saveAs' + i).selectize({
       options: saveAsOptions, 
       placeholder: '- Fields -'
    });
    
    i++;
});

function generateSaveAs(id){
    return '<select id="saveAs' + id + '"></select>';
}
```

Comment: If you click the add button again then the first one added should hide or it can be removed from DOM?

Comment: Or do you want to reset all selections when add button is clicked?

Comment: @planet260 If I select the full name in the first `<select>` it should not be visible in the second or third`<select>`

Comment: Oh so you want to select each option only once..right?

Comment: @planet260 yes that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So every time you are creating a new drop down you are inserting static values. By analyzing the code I see the selected value always have a class item. So what we can do is create a new array to show in dropdown and filter out the ones already selected. And then we can bind it in drop down.

To filter out you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
saveAsOptionsFiltered = saveAsOptions; //Initialize with your all drop down options
$(".item").each(function(index,element) {
    /*Filter out the already selected ones*/
    saveAsOptionsFiltered = saveAsOptionsFiltered.filter(function (savevalue) {return savevalue.text !== $(element).text() }); 
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KrdQ/33/)

I have not handled the condition when all are selected and you stop adding more I have just shared the code in which you can filter out the selected ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot @planet260, I'll just figure out the next steps. Hope I can figure it out myself. :)